# Use today's date as the default value for a Query String paramater?

Tags: data-view-web-part, query-string, parameter

This is what I have so far but I cannot figure out how to set the default value to today's date if the parameter is not passed in the query string.

```
<ParameterBinding Name="meetingDay" Location="QueryString(meetingDay)" DefaultValue="???"/>
```

Comment: Do you want to do TODAY calculations in a List/Library **View** ?

Comment: No. I want to show recurring events for a certain date span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I have to use the Today CAML variable. I was able to do what I need with:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="QueryString(meetingDay);CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
```